# "install it in place" - install what in place?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

From a dessicant humidifier manual (I have no illustrations, only an excerpt)

> Continuous Water Drainage.
>
> The unit features a continuous drainage port. Using a plastic pipe (with an inner diameter of 10mm), insert into drain hole (on intermediate plate), reach out from side of water tank, install **it** in place, and arrange the drain pipe.

My understanding is that the user is asked to extend his hand (reach out) from the side of the water tank (the unit's cavity that is used to accomodate the water tank), and when to install *something* in its proper place.

But install what? To install the pipe? To install the intermediate plate? Or the water tank?

I can't imagine the contraption. A pipe inserted into the water tank which is then installed in its place? A pipe inserted instead of the water tank? A pipe-plate combination inserted somewhere?

After the mysterious "intermediate plate" (is it an integral part of the construction, or something like a flat bushing?), the sentence is a puzzle.

Comment: Poorly written instructions. The problem begins with "Using".

Comment: @TRomano - I know. (0:

Comment: Possibly the "pipe" is the antecedent to "it". Is the "intermediate plate" a diagram?

Comment: There may be a clue in the fact that the instructions refer to the *inner* diameter of the plastic pipe, which would be relevant only if something is inserted into it.

Comment: Does the drain pipe fit inside the plastic pipe whose inner diameter is 10mm?

Comment: @TRomano - oh, so there could be *different* pipes? I thought that it was the selfsame pipe (0:

Comment: Not sure if "plastic pipe" and "drain pipe" are the same pipe. There is a slim chance that "it" might *anticipate* "drain pipe" rather than refer back to "plastic pipe" or "plate".

Comment: @TRomano - I wonder if this plastic pipe is a short rigid pipe (to serve as a nozzle from which the condensate will drip) or a long flexible pipe..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common for room dehumidifiers to have a removable reservoir to collect water. The reservoir can be dumped when it becomes full.

But these units also have a port in the housing for inserting a tube that bypasses the reservoir, so that the water can be continuously drained, thereby eliminating the need to dump the reservoir and allowing the unit to work continuously. (When the reservoir becomes full they stop automatically.)

A pipe about 200mm in length passes through the port in the housing and connects to a pipe inside the unit.

One end of the 200mm pipe is usually [male-threaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_of_connectors_and_fasteners). That threaded connector remains outside the unit's housing to allow a garden hose to be attached, to carry the water to a floor drain, say.

The threaded connector has a flange that butts against the housing.[image]

Comment: Accept my virtual hugs, TRomano! So the "thin" part of the 10-mm inner-bore *plastic pipe* connects to the *drain pipe* that usually drips water into the water tank (which has been taken out for the occasion)?

Comment: On most of these units, the continuous drainage connection is located just above the reservoir, so there is no need to remove the reservoir from the unit in order to use the continuous drainage method.

Comment: Is there a good manual online containing a description of this construction? Could you reference the source of the image, perhaps? (I will try to look myself using keywords, but not sure yet which keywords would serve best).

Comment: The pipe with the 10mm inner diameter slips onto a drip tube whose outer diameter is 10mm.

Comment: I took the picture myself :-)  Went down to the basement.  I dump the reservoir manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19919/discussion-between-copperkettle-and-tromano).

Comment: **[I found it](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/243969/Lg-Ld450eal.html?page=12)**: they call the *plastic pipe* "the threaded drain hose connector" in a manual for your dehumidifier.